# How to call model in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I'm writing a project with Django that can manage citizens with their passports. But today when I created an HTML page to represent the database, I have encountered an error.
My purpose of this webpage is show to user the info includes (**citizen name, citizen sex, the birthday of citizen, passport type, passport number, and valid time of citizen's passport**).

All of citizen information, I have put in Citizen table. With passport of citizen, I have put in Passport table.
The HTML page have represented all the information of Citizen table, but cannot represent informations in Passport table and I don't know why.

I don't know what I have wrong.

Here is my code:
**models.py**

```
class Passport(models.Model):
    Number = models.CharField(max_length=8, default=1)
    pType = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    validTime = models.DateField()
    pLocation = models.ForeignKey(Manager, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        null=True, default=None, related_name="passport",
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.Number} ({self.pType})" 

class Citizen(models.Model):
    sID = models.OneToOneField(
        Passport, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        default=1,
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    year = models.DateField()
    code = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} ({self.sex})"
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'citizens'
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index", ),
    path("<int:citizen_id>", views.citizen, name="citizen"),
    path("<int:citizen_id>/passport", views.passport, name="passport")
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseBadRequest, HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.urls import reverse

from .models import Citizen, Passport

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, "citizens/index.html", {
        "citizens": Citizen.objects.all()
    })

def citizen(request, citizen_id):
    try:
        citizen = Citizen.objects.get(code=citizen_id)
    except Citizen.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Citizen not found")
    return render(request, "citizens/citizen.html", {
        "citizen": citizen,
        
        
    })


def passport(request, citizen_id):
    try:
        passport = Passport.objects.get(Number=passport_id)
        citizen = Citizen.objects.get(code=citizen_id)
    except KeyError:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest("Bad request: No passport found")
    except Citizen.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest("Bad request: No citizen found")
    except Passport.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest("Bad request: No passport found")    
    return HttpResponseRedirect("citizen", args=(citizen_id,))
```

And the HTML page: **citizen.html**

```
{% extends "citizens/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Citizen {{ citizen.sID }}</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>Tên công dân: {{ citizen.name }} </li>
        <li>Giới tính: {{ citizen.sex }}</li>
        <li>Năm sinh: {{ citizen.year }}</li>
    </ul>

    <h2>Passport:</h2>
    <ul>
        
        <li>Loại hộ chiếu: {{ passport.pType }} </li>
        <li>Số hộ chiếu: {{ passport.Number }}</li>
        <li>Thời hạn hiệu lực: {{ passport.validTime }}</li>
        
    </ul>

    <a href="{% url 'citizens:index' %}">Quay lại</a>
{% endblock %}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only passed `citizen` into the context (you haven't passed `passport` in the context). To access the related `Passport` of the citizen you can write `citizen.sID` (the name of your `OneToOneField`), hence in your template you can write:

```
<h2>Passport:</h2>

<ul>
    <li>Loại hộ chiếu: {{ citizen.sID.pType }} </li>
    <li>Số hộ chiếu: {{ citizen.sID.Number }}</li>
    <li>Thời hạn hiệu lực: {{ citizen.sID.validTime }}</li>
    
</ul>
```